# disnake.py Bot for tracking users

Tags: python, disnake

I tried to make a discord bot that tracks who logged in and out, but I failed. Please help me, thank you.

````
from disnake.ext import commands

intents = disnake.Intents.default() #
intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print('Бот готов к работе.')

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
if before.status != disnake.Status.online and after.status == disnake.Status.online:
print(f'{after.name} зашел в сеть.')
elif before.status == disnake.Status.online and after.status !=:
print(f'{after.name} вышел из сети.')
disnake.Status.online
bot.run("TOKEN")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the [Intents.members](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/clients.html#disnake.Intents.members) intent in your code.
Also go to the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and the Bot section to enable the `Members` intent.

```py
from disnake.ext import commands

intents = disnake.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print('Бот готов к работе.')

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
   if before.status != disnake.Status.online and after.status == disnake.Status.online:
      print(f'{after.name} зашел в сеть.')
   elif before.status == disnake.Status.online and after.status != disnake.Status.online:
      print(f'{after.name} вышел из сети.')

bot.run("TOKEN")
```